# A faster way to decompress a text file that uses a unique form of compression

Tags: c#, compression, run-length-encoding

I dont know if this type of compression is used else where, but this is how it works. It uses 4 characters. The first character, a "ú" indicates that compression follows. The next 2 characters indicate, in HEX, how many of the 4th position are to be repeated. For example:

> 22ú05hú0C0AFC001

would be:

> 22hhhhh000000000000AFC001

I am able to do this but it runs VERY slowly. A 20k file can take 5 minutes or more.

Here is my code:

```
public string doDecompression(string Content)
{
    string pattern = @"ú...";
    Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);

    foreach (Match match in rgx.Matches(Content))
    {
        // Gets the raw Hex code
        string hex = match.ToString().Substring(1, 2);

        // Converts Hex code to an Integer 
        int convertedHex = Int32.Parse(hex, NumberStyles.HexNumber);

        // Gets the character to repeat
        string character = match.ToString().Substring(3, 1);

        // Converts the character to repeat into
        // a "char" so I can use it in the line below
        char repeatingChar = character[0];

        // Creates a string out of the repeating characters 
        string result = new String(repeatingChar, convertedHex);

        // This does the actual replacing of the text
        Content = Content.Replace(match.ToString(), result); 
    }

    return Content;
}
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Use a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Why don't you just enumerate the entire string as a character-array, and build a new string properly?

Comment: @Slaks  Do you mean use StringBuidler instead the the Content.Replace line?

Comment: Yes; exactly.  You're creating far too many strings.

Comment: Agree with @EBrown. Also in this compression method you can split the file to several files and process them in parallel - just make sure that you don't splitin the middle of the 4 chars

Comment: Even if the quadratic cost problem is fixed the constant work that you perform per element is high. Regex, int parsing, substring, ... All of those are heavy when you need to do it for each character.

Comment: What text encoding is that ú?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're seeing here is a variation of the [RLE algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding).

You don't really need regular expressions to do the job, let alone expensive operations with immutable strings.

Try the following approach:

```
public static IEnumerable<char> Decompress(string compressed)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < compressed.Length; )
    {
        var c = compressed[i++];
        if(c == 'ú')
        {
            var count = int.Parse(compressed.Substring(i, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
            i += 2;

            c = compressed[i++];

            foreach(var character in Enumerable.Repeat(c, count))
                yield return character;
        }
        else
        {
            yield return c;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks great but I'm having trouble getting the characters to repeat and count do it this way.

Comment: @JimDel Updated my answer. Beware of tricky `for` and increments.

Comment: That `foreach(var character in Enumerable.Repeat(c, count))` seems pretty useless. The returned character is the same (namely 'c') throughout the whole loop, so don't bother  making a list of them; just use `for (Int32 rep=0; rep < count; rep++) yield return c;`